# problem in Condition chaining

Tags: php

I am very new in php. I am having a problem in condition checking. I have the condition chain like this

```
if(condition1){

    if (condition2){ 
       Statement1;
    }else{
       Statement2;
    }
else{

    if (same condition2){
      Statement3;
    }else{
      Statement4;
}
```

Now when I am writing this like I am having errors -

```
if (condition1) "AND". (condition2)

     Statement1;
if (condition1) "AND". (!condition2)

     Statement2;
if (!condition1) "AND". (condition2)

     Statement3;
if (!condition1) "AND". (!condition2)

     Statement4;
```

Can anyone enlighten me where I am wrong?

Here is the real code I am writing -

```
if (!isset($store['stationfilter'])) "AND". ($fromdate_display == $todate_display)

 $storeSql_current = sprintf($sql_current, ''); //error 1

if (!isset($store['stationfilter'])) "AND". (!$fromdate_display == $todate_display)     //error2

 $storeSql_otherThancurrent = sprintf($sql_otherThancurrent, ''); //error3

if (isset($store['stationfilter'])) "AND". ($fromdate_display == $todate_display)    //error4

 $storeSql_current = sprintf($sql_current, "AND" . $store['stationfilter']);  //error5

if (isset($store['stationfilter'])) "AND". (!$fromdate_display == $todate_display)   //error6

 $storeSql_otherThancurrent = sprintf($sql_otherThancurrent, "AND" . $store['stationfilter']);   //error7
```

Please tell me where I am wrong.

Thanks,
Neel

Comment: What do you think `(condition1) "AND". (condition2)` should do? What meaning should putting a sting `"AND"` after a variable `condition1` have? PHP probably throws a syntax error, which is supposed to give you a hint about what's wrong. And especially when you are new you should read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php), which should help you in most of your problems.

Comment: your second code makes no sense. what are these REAL conditions? there are probably easiest way to achieve the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write like this:

```
if ($condition1 && $condition2) ....
```

Comment: Its not working - throwing syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND in /home/foldername/public_html/admin/program.php on line 152

Comment: I am sorry it not working, but just tell you how to write `and` in a if statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($cond1 && $cond2) {

        # stmt1

    } else if ($cond1) {

        # stmt2

    } else if ($cond2) {

        # stmt3

    } else {

        # stmt4

    }
```

I've amended the above with your actual conditions, below. I've also taken a guess at what your statements are supposed to look like...

```
if ( isset($store['stationfilter']) && $fromdate_display === $todate_display ) {

    $storeSql_current = sprintf('%s AND %s', $sql_current, $store['stationfilter']);

} else if ( isset($store['stationfilter']) ) {

    $storeSql_otherThancurrent = sprintf('%s AND %s', $sql_otherThancurrent, $store['stationfilter']);

} else if ( $fromdate_display === $todate_display ) {

    $storeSql_current = (string) $sql_current;

} else {

    $storeSql_otherThancurrent = (string) $sql_otherThancurrent;

}
```

If what you're doing is to build a sql statement, then this approach may be dangerous because of the potential for SQL Injection.  If `$store['stationfilter']`, `$sql_current` or `$sql_otherThancurrent` (the data) are coming from an untrusted source (all sources are untrusted unless the source is code you have written) then you should, at minimum, be using the database adapter to quote the data or, better, using parameterised queries.